# C++11: function template: passing parameters by reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

There is a kind of template function to pass a parameter by reference + callback function, but there is a problem if the parameters are passed by reference to callback function then compiler is throwing an error:

> no matching function for call to `func(int&, void (&)(int&))`.

What's wrong?

```
template<typename T> 
using func_t = void(T);

template<typename T>
void func(T& arg, func_t<T> callback) {
    callback(arg);
} 

void func1(int arg) {  }
void func2(int& arg) { } //<-- (1)

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    func(x, func1);
    func(x, func2); //<-- (2) compilation error 
}
```

Comment: As far, as I understand, in template you specify that your callback takes argument by value. Probably, you should overload your `func` to make it possible.

Comment: throw error:  call of overloaded 'func(int&, void (&)(int))' is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deduction of `T` in the second call fails because `T` occurs in two deduced contexts which deduce *different* values of `T`.

In the first parameter, `T& arg`, `T` is deduced to `int` since the argument `x` has type `int`.

In the second parameter, `func_t<T>`, `T` is deduced to `int&` since the argument `func2` has type `void(int&)`.

Since the two deduced types, `int` and `int&`, differ for the same parameter, deduction *fails.*

However, you can do the right thing by explicitly specifying that `T` should be `int&`:

```
func<int&>(x, func2); // ok
```